# Accessing Elements of Group in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap, dihedral-groups, sagemath

```
gap> G:=DihedralGroup(20);
<pc group of size 20 with 3 generators>

gap> Elements(G);
[ <identity> of ..., f1, f2, f3, f1*f2, f1*f3, f2*f3, f3^2, f1*f2*f3, f1*f3^2, f2*f3^2, f3^3, f1*f2*f3^2, f1*f3^3, f2*f3^3, f3^4, f1*f2*f3^3, f1*f3^4, f2*f3^4, f1*f2*f3^4 ]
```

I am trying to do some calculations on elements of `G`, say  the order of `(f1*f2*f3)`.

I don't know how to access elements of `G` using the comments directly.

I tried to assign `f3:=Elements(G)[3];` which worked but when group size is large (say $500, 1000$), knowing which index of the list corresponds to which index, have no clue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is a purely technical question about using GAP, and not suitable for this forum.

Comment: But maybe it makes more sense just to answer the question! You can access $\mathtt{f1,f2.f3,\ldots}$ using the function $\mathtt{GeneratorsOfGroup}$.

Comment: or use G.3 to get the third generator etc.

Comment: You may want to learn more about the GAP programming language: see e.g. https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap3.html#X7CC5B0347F8EC820, https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap4.html and https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://stackoverflow.com or in a GAP mailing list or support website.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `AssignGeneratorVariables` (see [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap37_mj.html#X814203E281F3272E)), for example:

```
gap> G:=DihedralGroup(20);
<pc group of size 20 with 3 generators>
gap> AssignGeneratorVariables(G);
#I  Assigned the global variables [ f1, f2, f3 ]
gap> Order(f1*f2*f3);
2
```

but with care - for a new group you'd have to call it again, otherwise they will still refer to the old group.

Actually, `AssignGeneratorVariables` is only usable for small examples, when you can write indices by hand. Better practices would rely on the approaches, mentioned in comments above.

As a small example to demonstrate capabilities, just to give a flavour of how it could look like, let's calculate how `f1` conjugates generators of the group `G`:

```
gap> G:=DihedralGroup(20);
<pc group of size 20 with 3 generators>
gap> gens:=GeneratorsOfGroup(G);
[ f1, f2, f3 ]
gap> a:=gens[1];
f1
gap> for g in gens do
> Print( g, " -> ", g^a, "\n");
> od;
f1 -> f1
f2 -> f2*f3^4
f3 -> f3^4
gap>
```

The above calculation may print the output nicely, but on the other hand it's not usable. A better approach could be to save it to a list, which then can be used in other calculations. That can be done using `do` loops as well, but also may be written using a more compact notation:

```
gap> s := List(gens, g -> g^a);
[ f1, f2*f3^4, f3^4 ]
```